# How to remove color bleed stain?

Tags: cleaning, clothing, laundry

Recently, I bought some new cloths, one of them is a jean, and some other white cloths. By accident, I washed the jeans together with other light colored cloths, and the white cloths got colored. When I finished washing, I didn't notice since it was at night and I couldn't see clearly. So when I noticed, the cloths were already dry.  Immediately I tried using bleaches but unfortunately it didn't work, is there any way to remove the stain?

Comment: I bet you meant to say, that the *white cloths* got colored and not the light colored ones, right?

Comment: @Alex yes..,.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would have been easier if done before they dried, but neither of us can turn back time. Some ideas can be found in the answers to [How to remove pigments from white clothes that have been accidentally laundered?](//lifehacks.stackexchange.com/q/6755/4490) on this site, and some more from searching for [remove color bleed stains](//google.com/search?q=remove+color+bleed+stains) at google.

The general idea seems to be one of the below:

- Presoak for several hours using a non-chlorine (oxygen based) bleach (possible with a little vinegar) before a normal wash. Might need to be repeated
- Use a color remover product (according to its manual)
- Soak using a chlorine based bleach, but for a shorter amount of time like 10-15 min, before washing

So there you have the basic options, and now lets leave it up to the community to provide the really hackish solutions, if they exist.